# Convert CrmFloat to double value C#

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

How to convert CrmFloat value to double value C# ?

I have tried the given below code. but does not works.

```
Convert.ToDouble(crmfloatval);
```

Comment: What does "not works" mean? What happens? What's the type of `crmfloatval`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `crmfloatval.Value` to get the stored value, which [according to documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928962.aspx) is already a double.

> **CrmFloat** - Double type, while CRM calls this a float, it is actually a double for money, use CrmMoney - Converts from a double type

For example

```
double value = crmfloatval.IsNull == false ? crmfloatval.Value : 0
```